# cannot find -l-static-libgcc when building gcc from source

Tags: gcc

I try to build gcc (9.3.0) from source on ubuntu focal using the following configure call:

```
./configure --enable-shared --enable-multilib --prefix=/opt/gcc
```

The configure runs OK but when building/linking I get the following error:

```
libtool: link: gcc -shared  -fPIC -DPIC  .libs/lto-plugin.o   -l  -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc ../libiberty/pic/libiberty.a   -Wl,-soname -Wl,liblto_plugin.so.0 -o .libs/liblto_plugin.so.0.0.0
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -l-static-libgcc
```

It seems that some gcc linker options have been but in the wrong place. I have the same mistake with another version of gcc (6.5.0) so the problem seems to be on my side. Would you have any idea about what is wrong with my settings ? Am I missing a dependency ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by building gcc in a directory outside of the source directory. This is probably one reason why this was strongly recommended in the documentation.